# Bracket placement

Tags: grammar, parentheses, square-brackets, braces

My idea of using of various brackets is unclear; can anybody clarify as to where exactly I use *()* and *[]*? Furtermore, are *{}* used in regular grammar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses are used to indicate, well, parenthetical thoughts.

> We discussed the value (or lack
>   thereof) of homeopathic medicine.

Square brackets are used to indicate alterations, omissions, or supplementary material in quotations.

> I believe it was Thomas Paine who said
>   "These [the years leading up to the
>   American Revolution] are times that
>   try men's souls."

I cannot think of a use for curly braces in ordinary writing.